# understand if a shell process is in background?

Tags: shell, process, mutt

I keep an instance of mutt idling on a terminal, if it is on index or pager I want it to be able to receive a macro from an external process (AutoKey or xdotool etc..), but the external program need to check mutt isn't running some sub process (emacs, shell...), how to check?

It is Linux, so if some `/proc/$pid/*` could work would be fine.

Comment: This seems very fragile. No matter how you do it, there's a high potential for race conditions. Why would you run a macro from the outside rather than run another instance of mutt?

Comment: @Gilles running another instance is the plan B if this doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do  this to emit child processes of mutt:

```
pgrep -l -P $(pgrep -x mutt)
```

[`pgrep` man page](http://man.cx/pgrep)